# Java | String Types

Tags: java, string

I ran into a problem that I don't understand. **nextLine()** should be for sentences, right?

```
System.out.println("Enter film's name");
a = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("What number did the film released?");
b = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Who's the director?");
c = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("How long is the film in minutes?");
d = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Have you seen the movie? Yes/No?");
e = scan.next();
System.out.println("Mark for the film?");
f = scan.nextDouble();
```

It runs correctly till the releasing date, and then it shows "Who is the director" and "How long is the film" together and doesn't work like it supposed to work.

How can you use **nextLine();** and why doesn't it work for me?

Comment: can u please describe your actual problem ?

Comment: Similar question already answered. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Comment: nextInt scans the next token as an int value. so you must append \n whenever you are taking integer input

Comment: So the answer is: add a `scan.nextLine()` after the nextInt call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `Scanner.nextInt()` does not reads to the next line. So you need to issue `nextLine(`) calls too and throw away their content:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter film's name");
    String a = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What number did the film released?");
    int b = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine(); // this
    System.out.println("Who's the director?");
    String c = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("How long is the film in minutes?");
    int d = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine(); // this
    System.out.println("Have you seen the movie? Yes/No?");
    String e = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Mark for the film?");
    double f = scan.nextDouble();
    scan.nextLine(); // after nextDouble() too
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. Solved!

Comment: Would you mind accept this answer then?

Answer (score 1):

The buffer is stuffed really reset your scanner after every consecutive calls.  scan.reset(); . The reason is that previous characters are cached in the input stream.

Comment: Also nextInt() does not consume the last newline ascii character in your input. To remdey this, use scan.nextLine() to get int value then Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine()). However get the integer first , and check if it  is a integer then perform the parseInt conversion.Don't use nextInt() or next.